# programmatically animate window form in WPF

Tags: wpf, jquery-animate

I have to increase height of windows form after I clicked one button.
I need to do this programmatically cause I try to do this with xml code and did it well ,but it work every time I click button, I need to animate just once with clicking just one button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [double animation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimation(v=vs.110).aspx) to change the height property.In your button_click event write the code for double animation.

```
 DoubleAnimation dblanim = new DoubleAnimation();
            dblanim.To =200;
            dblanim.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
            this.BeginAnimation(HeightProperty, dblanim);
```

use dblanim.To property to set the height of your window.

Comment: thank you so much, it working good, but when it increase height,bottom of the windows form goes black a second and back to normal again,why??and how can I fix it?

Comment: no such behavior is hapenning with me..u may need to check your xaml.